# Instalation grub on flash disk

Tags: ubuntu, usb, grub

How can I install grub on USB flsah device(Pen-drive). I try to `grub-install /dev/sdb`. But there was an error: `grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'`. So i tried this way: `sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux-generic` but result was the same. I use Live USB system to restore my broken system. My system is broken because grub is missing. I wanted to try start system with grub on flash disk. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't know what i do wrong.

Comment: Plug in your USB and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: `Disk /dev/sdb: 7,5 GiB, 8054112256 bytes, 15730688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000`
 This is the output of `fdisk`

Comment: You do not try to install grub on the USB-Stick, from where you start your live-Session?

Comment: Ofcourse I do not. Now I install new ubuntu not from liveUSB. And error is the same.

Comment: Maybe your USB stick contain an hybrid ISO ,Use Gparted to format it (F32) then mount it and run the following `grub-install --boot-directory=mount_point/boot /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve problem. I used gParted, type:`ext3` flag:`bios_grub`. After this `grub-install /dev/sXY` works perfectly.
To start system with grub on USB I run grub command line and use following:
`grub> set root=(hd1,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd /initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
grub> boot`